# Can't make Laravel eloquent hasManyThrough work

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship

I need help.

I'm making a sort of like reddit website.

I need query that would give me the profile of the user and his karmas through the threads that the user have made.

Tables and relationship:

> User has one profile
>    User has many threadKarmaPoints through threads

```
    public function threadKarmaPoints() {
    return $this->hasManyThrough(
        'App\Models\ThreadKarmaView',
        'App\Models\ThreadView',
        'userId',
        'threadId',
        'userId',
        'threadId');
}
```

Query: (I need to get the user through username and not by id)

```
$user = UserView::where('username', $username)
            ->with(['profile', 'threadKarmaPoints'])
            ->firstOrFail();
```

This gives me empty array. Although if I remove the `'threadKarmaPoints'` in with, it gives me the user and his profile so I think there must be wrong with my `threadKarmaPoints` relationship.

Additional question: in eloquent query, should `->with()` comes first or `->where()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the following example and read the comments next to each param in `hasManyThrough` relationship below:

```
user
    id - integer

thread
    id - integer
    user_id - integer

karma_points
    id - integer
    thread_id - integer
```

And this is how your relationship should be like

```
public function threadKarmaPoints() {
    return $this->hasManyThrough(
        'App\Models\ThreadKarmaView', //target entity
        'App\Models\ThreadView', //go-through entity
        'user_id', // Foreign key of User on ThreadView table
        'thread_id', // Foreign key of ThreadView on ThreadKarmaView table
        'id', //Local key of User table
        'id' //Local key of ThreadView table
     );
}
```

**Final edit:**

The code below should work

```
public function threadPostKarmaPoints() {
    return $this->hasManyThrough(
        'App\Models\Views\ThreadKarmaView',
        'App\Models\Views\ThreadView',
        'createdBy',
        'threadId',
        'userId',
        'threadId');
}
```

Comment: I've already look at that example countless times. I'm pretty sure I got every parameter right. I'm using camel casing on my database, and the primary key of my table is tableId so for users, it's userId, and for thread, it's threadId

Comment: Can u drop your migrations for User, Thread and Karma points table and also add their entity files aka models and give me a link?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/UGafdp4X I have changed my file directory for my models btw, so the code in the paste bin is slightly different here.

Comment: I've made a final update of the answer, awaiting the results :)

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply. Been a busy day. But yeah, it worked. Thank you so much. I forgot I renamed the column userId in threads to createdBy. Silly mistake. Thanks!